# Mysterious frame in Firefox

Tags: support

[image: screenshot]

At the top and left I sometimes get an orange strip about 2px wide. It changes colour on hover, as seen on screenshot. But when I try to click anything, it disappear.

Does it happen to you, too? Or is it some bizarre local bug on my side?

Comment: Wow, do people still use Firefox? ;)

Comment: can you please tell me where exactly, I can not identify easily in top left

Comment: @Clive I use only FireFox :) I hope you are using chrome

Comment: @Bala I disavowed from it about 4-5 years ago when there were so many bugs and "design decisions", **cough**, that I couldn't do my job properly with it. Never looked back from Chrome, it's a much happier life for a web developer :)

Comment: @Bala Was tempted to say "no, I use IE, of course" ;)

Comment: Could it be related to the [top bar bleed-through](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2764/banner-bleeds-through-top-bar) @Mołot? If memory serves you had an interim fix for that, if you apply said fix does the problem disappear?

Comment: @Clive no it is not related, Its about the double color http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210346/top-bar-with-double-color

Comment: @Clive nope, I disabled custom styling plugin altogether before reporting, but it happened even with it, just looking a bit different (no transparency, so no onhover changes).

Comment: @Clive and yes, when I need to make my scripts FF compatible, I don't bother to run separate browser just for Stack sites. Why would I? It seems FF is officially supported.

Comment: @Mołot It was just a joke, in my (immediate, and probably rather insular) experience, not as many devs use FF as did "back in the day"

Answer (score 3):

This is Firefox 26.0 on Mavericks for me:

[image]

I don't see an orange line...

Comment: thanks for sharing the mod view, looks nice and works perfect in FF 25.0.1

Comment: Well I see it randomly :D But only on Drupal Answers. Not on Stack Overflow or metas. Magic, maybe?

Comment: @Mołot Seeing it randomly makes tracking it down even more fun :) The orange looks suspiciously close to the orange used on SO, I wonder if there's some sort of weird DNS caching issue with Stack assets?

Comment: I thought I saw it yesterday, but it could have been on one of the sites I was working on.  I don't see it now, though.  If it goes away on click, it may be a rogue :focus state.

Comment: @MPD Thanks, so maybe that's not just me :D

Comment: @Mołot are you talking about this http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=7ad1fee , whenever I refresh it loads first with grey and my internet speed is 4mbps, I don't know why only stack site is loading slowly, so I can see this grey bar easily while loading. do you face same like this

Comment: @Bala nope, I see orange bar and everything loads blinking fast.